# Detect when touch user pulls finger up in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, button

Sorry if this is a repeated question but i couldn't find any aswers.

Basically, I'm developing a web app that has a button in it.

I want that button to highlight in two different scenarios:

-If the user is on a non-touch (desktop) device, the button will highlight if the mouse is on top of it and get back to normal when it's not.

-If the user is on a touch device WITHOUT a mouse, the button will highlight if it's touched and get back to normal when the touching stops.

The desktop part is working fine, but the touch part have a problem: to get the button back to normal, I have to click somewhere else after clicking it, just stop touching the screen doesn't work.

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

JS Code:

```
if (!this.isTouch) {
  document.getElementById("search_button").addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
    highlightButton();
  });
  document.getElementById("search_button").addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    restoreButton();
  });
}
else if (window.matchMedia("(any-pointer: none)").matches) {
  document.getElementById("search_button").addEventListener("touchstart", function () {
    highlightButton();
    });
  document.getElementById("search_button").addEventListener("touchend", function () {
      restoreButton();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several touch events listed as well that may be of use for you, this extends touch devices such as tablets and phones:

```
  el.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchcancel", handleCancel, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchmove", handleMove, false);
```

read more at [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine also `touchcancel` event :

```js
  addEventListener( "touchcancel", function ( event ) {
      console.log( "BREAK" );
      restoreButton();
    }, false );
```

Comment: It's normal practice to print in log every user action? Sorry, I'm just starting with web development

Comment: console.log is only for dev to make easy see what really happen. Best way is to remove console.log on production . I suggest you also to use  breakpoint/debugger in breakpoint whole execution of program stops and then you can check current local scope or add some variable to watch list. Find on google who to use debugger in chrome. `console.log` is ok debugger is ultimate for detecting buggs or app flow. If you have windows but you wanna debug on iOS than use alert(" MY VAR IS = " + someVar ) it is only solution in that case.

Comment: When you fix you part of code then remove console.log also loops are most dangerus place for console.log dont forget ! Easy can freez you browser if you have lot of iteration...